# Can I trigger a release pipeline using azure cli

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

I have a suitation where I have to trigger my release pipeline using power shell so I have to use azure cli so is their any command which trigger my release pipeline using azure cli

Answer (score 7):

Please take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines/release?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-devops-az-pipelines-release-create)

```
az pipelines release create [--artifact-metadata-list]
                            [--definition-id]
                            [--definition-name]
                            [--description]
                            [--detect {false, true}]
                            [--only-show-errors]
                            [--open]
                            [--org]
                            [--project]
```

Please install first [Azure DevOps CLI Extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension)

I just run this and release was created and queued:

```
az pipelines release create --org https://dev.azure.com/thecodemanual --project "Devops Manual" --definition-id 1
```

Comment: and you can also do `az devops invoke` and then use the devops rest api incase the DevOps extension has not yet implemented a complex feature. The DevOps api to create release is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Comment: Release will be not only created but also queued.

Comment: My release pipeline is already created I just want to queue that pipeline so by using this command it will queue my release pipeline ?

Comment: Yes. It does not create a new release  definition. It uses existing to create release and deploy it. Pleade try it.

Answer (score -2):

Incase you are looking for login to azure devops through az cli refer below cmd before firing the cmd suggested by @krzysztof

```
echo  $azpat | az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/yourorg/
```

Comment: This is a commentary on @krysztof's answer, but doesn't answer the original question. Such suggestions should not be posted as new answers unless they _also_ answer the original question.